# Getting Error while running npm run ionic:build --prod

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

> [14:39:19]  ionic-app-script task: "build"  [14:39:19]  Error: Failed
>   to transpile TypeScript  Error: Failed to transpile TypeScript
>       at errorCheckProgram (/var/www/html/jp_app_pwa/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:119:39)
>       at Object. (/var/www/html/jp_app_pwa/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:89:21)
>       at step (/var/www/html/jp_app_pwa/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:32:23)
>       at Object.next (/var/www/html/jp_app_pwa/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:13:53)
>       at fulfilled (/var/www/html/jp_app_pwa/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:4:58)
>
> npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-62-generic npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node"
>   "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "ionic:build" "--prod" npm ERR! node v6.11.3 npm
>   ERR! npm  v3.10.10 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! jaypore@0.0.1
>   ionic:build: `ionic-app-scripts build` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the jaypore@0.0.1 ionic:build script
>   'ionic-app-scripts build'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest
>   version of node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most
>   likely a problem with the jaypore package, npm ERR! not with npm
>   itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm
>   ERR!     ionic-app-scripts build npm ERR! You can get information on
>   how to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs
>   jaypore npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info
>   via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls jaypore npm ERR! There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /var/www/html/jp_app_pwa/npm-debug.log

**ionic info:**

cli packages: (`/var/www/html/jp_app_pwa/node_modules`)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0 browser 5.0.1 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
Node : v6.11.3
npm  : 3.10.10 
OS   : Linux 4.4
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : legacy
```

Comment: did you try this?  `npm run ionic:build --prod` and try to Upgrade your  typescript

Comment: you got any solution to this ?